# A property of a first countable spaces

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove that if $X$ is a first countable space, then for every subset $A$ of $X$ such that for every $K$ a compact subset of $X$, $A\cap K$ is closed in $K$, then $A$ is closed in $X$. Does anyone any idea how can I prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea, I'm leaving the details for you to fill in.

Suppose $A$ is not closed. Take a point $x\in \overline A\setminus A$. Then there is a sequence of elements $x_n\in A$ convergent to $x$. Consider $K=\{x\}\cup\{x_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$. Show that this set is compact (hint: one of the sets in any open cover will contain $x$), but $K\cap A$ is not closed in $K$.

Comment: I had the same idea. But I do not see how to have a contradiction.

Comment: I will add some more details then.

Comment: Thank you. It will be great

Comment: I see your idea. However is $K\cap A= \{x_n : n \in \mathbb N\}$ closed in $K$ ?

Comment: Woops, I meant "not closed" where I said "not open".

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand the contradiction here.

Comment: Do you fail to see why $K\cap A$ is not closed in $K$, or rather why that fact gives a contradiction?

Comment: I fail to see the contradiction.

Comment: We have proven "if $A$ is not closed, then $A\cap K$ is not closed in $K$ for some compact $K$". We get the original statement by taking the contrapositive of this.

Comment: I am not sure about that. Indeed the original statement is $$A \subset X,\,\text{if}\, \forall K \subset X, \text{ compact, } A\cap K \,\text{is closed in}\, K \implies A\, \text{is closed in } X$$

Comment: The contradiction may be to find a compact subset $K$ with $A\cap K$ closed in $K$

Comment: You are right sorry about my missunderstanding.